# Buck converter inductor waveform having high ripple and slow charging and fast discharging

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, inductor, buck

The following shows the voltage (green) and current waveform (yellow) across an inductor in a buck converter designed to step down 30 V to 15 V with 0.2 A output current.

The inductor values according to the design are 2.3 mH (toroidal Fe dust core), and the capacitor used is 10 μF. The switching frequency is 100 kHz.

All the waveforms even across the diode and the gate pulse are fine, except the inductor current wave form. Can someone suggest what I should look for?

[image]

Comment: Looks like textbook core saturation. What's the saturation spec of your inductor?

Comment: Surely you mean microhenry? Why is the voltage reading in amperes?

Comment: Can you post a schematic?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like hard saturation.  Past a certain current, your inductance crashes and therefore your dI/dt rises rapidly with a given voltage across it.  You want to make sure you're always going to be operating your peak current well below your inductor saturation threshold.